# umbraco deployed as azure web app - content not showing on site

Tags: azure, umbraco

I've got an umbraco site which I deploy to an azure web app service. The data is on an azure sql database. I have been able to deploy this successfully, and can verify that all the data I expect to be there is present in the content view.

However I have added content on various pages, in rich text editors, and on my local site I can see this content on the site. But on my deployed site the content in rich text editors is only visible on the content view, not on the site. I've tried publishing each item but nothing will appear.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a much experimenting.

I had not manually included in my project (and thus not deploying) Views/Partials/Grid/fanoe.cshtml. This file includes the  and I guess I was using some default template which is using this file, rather than the other grid templates in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco needs some additional configuration to be treated properly on Azure. It especially affects indexes and XML caching file.

Please check the following blog post made by one of the **Umbraco HQ Core developers - Sebastiaan Janssen**: https://cultiv.nl/blog/making-sure-your-umbraco-site-performs-on-azure/. Go step by step to ensure if your app is properly configured.

Going further you may be in need to also ensure proper **configuration for load balancing**, which you can find here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible

Comment: thanks! good things to look into. I suspect I'm making some more basic deployment mistake though

Comment: @JonnyCundall feel free to update your question and point specific problems if there will be any (hopefully not!) :) Happy coding!